# Spring Security 3: Setting up tomcat 6 for SSL

Tags: ssl, spring-mvc, spring-security, certificate, tomcat6

I am trying to setup spring security 3 running on tomcat 6 for SSL.

I need to test a secure-connection with `https` for which I configured SSL on tomcat successfully and then exported a certificate out of generated keystore but still my application doesn't run. It redirects me to https on port 8443 and says that "This webpage is not available".

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" requires-channel="https"/>
```

Could someone tell me what else do I need to do to test the secure connection for the login page?

Answer (score 0):

Is 8443 the proper HTTPS port for your Tomcat instance?  If not, you'll need a port-mapping inside your http element in spring security:

```
<http>
    ...
    <port-mappings>
      <port-mapping http="9080" https="9443"/>
    </port-mappings>
</http>
```

Comment: Yes 8443 is https port for my tomcat instance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change HTTP port to 80 and HTTPS to 433 in server.xml.
2. Make sure you don't have any port mappings in your  in the Spring context configuration file.
3. Restart Tomcat.
4. Mark this answer as useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have to configure your TOMCAT to work with SSL (in addition to all the things that are written above)

have a look [here](http://www.itworld.com/development/80705/how-enable-https-tomcat).

Hope this helps...

Ohad